# Multiple RSS Feeds iPhone Reader

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios4, rss, uinavigationcontroller

I am creating an iPhone app that will contain multiple RSS feeds.  I have already created a UITableView with one feed using the following tutorial:

http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/

I need your help in creating a UITableView with multiple feeds.

Thank you,

CKallemeres

Comment: So what is your question? I don't think we will write all code for you.

Comment: How to create a UITableView containing headings that direct to RSS feeds with a detail view allowing the user to see the feed text without having to open Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out NSOperationQueue and add each xml to be parsed to the OperationQueue.

Here is the documentation for it: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind piggy banking off of Google Reader, I've seen many apps that successfully use that as the aggregator. To have your application handle multiple feeds would be very resource/network intensive, in my opinion. A good example of an excellent Reader based app is [Reeder](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reeder/id325502379?mt=8).

If you still want to create your own custom aggregator solution, it still might be useful to work off of Google Reader to start (for development purposes) to at least understand how you'll handle multiple feeds rolling in. Also, I'd look into more server-side based solutions for providing that information as I still keep my opinion that handling that in the app itself would be excessive.